# pure-ftpd permission denied on external usb drive

Tags: permissions, ftp, ntfs

I have a sheevaplug PC (Debian installed) that I'm trying to setup my personal FTP server with. So far I was able to set up auto mounting and installed pure-ftpd. I currently have autofs setup to mount the external USB drive to the home dir of a user called "xt" (/home/xt/usb1)

Here's the mounting options I used:

```
usb1 -fstype=auto,umask=000,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,nosuid,nodev,user :/dev/sda1
```

And the `pure-ftpd` cmd:

```
pure-ftpd -S 400 -c 30 -B -j -E
```

With the way it is now, I'm able to browse all dirs fine, I can even upload, rename and delete files outside of the usb drive. However inside the usb drive, I can browse files only (denied access to downloads, uploads, delete, etc...).

I did an `ls -l /home/xt/usb1` and all dirs are listed as: `drwxrwxrwx` on the permissions colum so on paper, I should be able to do anything to the drive.

Answer (score 1):

After countless Google searches I finally found the solution. It turns out I couldn't even write files (rename, delete, etc...) as root locally on the usb drive.

This made me think the problem must be at the driver/firmware level and the fact that the drive is formatted ntfs. Apparently the Debian OS I installed on the plug shipped the regular `ntfs` drivers, which can only do read operations, so once I installed `ntfs-3g`, which has read and write compatibility, my ftp sever is all set now.